# how to parseInt null to 0 in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, wordpress

I am getting data as json from server, i need parse the json string into number, while parsing into number wherever the values are null is coming NaN in my ng repeat table. how can i replace NaN to 0 while parsing.

function:

```
 $scope.parseInt = function (data) {
            return parseInt(data);
        };
```

html:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in outlets">
            <td>{{ parseInt(item.offerID) }}</td>
```

how can i get 0 instead of NaN? thanks in advance.

Comment: `return(parseInt(data)||0)`

Comment: You can use `Number()` instead of `parseInt()` as long as you're sure you're never getting decimal numbers. Also `parseInt(item.offerID) || 0` should do the trick

Comment: @KKSK, it is working for you ?

Comment: i used the if isNaN is working for me. thanks - Alexandru-Ionut Mihai

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||`  which is equivalent of *null coalescing operator*.

```
<td>{{ parseInt(item.offerID) || 0 }}</td>
```

Comment: `null || parseInt(null)` would still be `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

try this in controller and try to avoid handling in HTML:

```
$scope.parseInt = function (data) {
        if (data == null) return 0;
           return parseInt(data);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use or operator in your function.

```
$scope.parseInt = function (data) {
            return parseInt(data) || 0;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical OR operator for null coalescing. In your case you could do it at the function level:

```
$scope.parseInt = function (data) {
  return parseInt(data, 10) || 0;
};
```

Or in the HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in outlets">
  <td>{{ parseInt(item.offerID) || 0 }}</td>
</tr>
```